# What is stored in a wp-postpass_[hash] cookie from an WorldPress site?

Tags: wordpress, cookies, passwords

I'd like to know what kind of content is stored in this cookie. I'm trying to make a login prompt for my flutter app, but for Data protection guidelines I'm not allowed to store the password of the website in the app (as hash) and now I'm trying if I can get determine if a user has entered the correct password out of the cookie or not.